# Is ASP.NET webhook supports webforms application to create custom receivers and senders?

Tags: asp.net-webhooks

Can we implement `asp.net` web-hooks in web-form based application having framework `.NET 4.5`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The samples [1] should generally work with WebForms as well. Let me know how it goes!

Henrik

[1] https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/tree/master/samples

Comment: Thanks alot @Henrik ,Sure I will :) may i know about CustomSender and CustomReceivers sample?and the sample[1] is AzureReceivers ?

Comment: Hi @Henrik, Do i need to create custom receivers for webform ?I checked for slack receivers its not working in asp.net weforms :(